# How can i set 10 lat lng value in between two locations waypoint in google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I show set of latitude and longitude values in google map route between two locations and need to indicate that lat long locations in marker in android

Comment: Add some code what u have tried and how u are getting location data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Location manger for receiving updates.

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[0]);
```

Here you can give the Interval in which you get the updates. You can give minimun distance between updates or a time Interval. As you want 10 markers so according to your distance between the starting point and destination you can give the parameters.

To display markers on map use

```
map.addmarker(markerOptions)
```

Here marker options means the icon, title etc of the marker.

If you want to display the default marker the pass something like this

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
    .title("Hello world"));
```